# Optimisation Options for Set of Similar Oracle Functions

Tags: oracle, function, optimization, plsql

I have three custom functions that do very similar things: they pull different data from the same, rather complicated set of joins -- generating the joined table is what takes the time -- and are usually all called in the same `select`. This is obviously inefficient and I would like to improve performance, but what is the best way to go about it?

- Create a materialised view of the complex join, covering all parameters, and just refer to this in each of the functions (or just omit the functions, altogether).
- Roll the three functions together and return all values at once in a custom type.
- Something else?

The first option seems, to a rookie like me, probably the best solution; but it obviously has the drawback of creating a pretty large materialised view, which would need maintenance (so it's refreshed as required); although this MV might be useful elsewhere... The second option would be a bit of a hack; but is there anything else that I haven't considered?

Comment: n.b., It would have to be a materialised view; if it were a regular view, it would (presumably) be executed every time it was needed, which is the same problem.

Comment: Can you post an example of one of these functions?

Comment: @Tony: I'm not sure if it would be cool to make my functions public; but the guts involve a big `select`, which is fairly straightforward save a `with` block, which is the source of the inefficiencies. Given that the `with` part is so transparent, it is well suited to be moved into an MV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would choose option 2 to be honest, unless you really want a materialised view. You can cast the function as a table so you can select from it as normal.

Comment: This is the option I'm going for as the materialised view would effectively summarise the largest table in the database (around 0.5GB in size), along with probably the second-largest... That won't do!

Comment: ...Consolidating the three functions into one reduced the query's runtime from 17 to 6 seconds. Yay :)

Comment: Although it does show just how slow these function calls are. We assume linearity -- which isn't a good assumption, but never mind -- then, suppose the base query (which also calls functions) runs in time _x_ and this function in _y_: _x_ + _y_ = 6 and _x_ + 3 _y_ = 17; therefore the base query runs in 0.5 seconds and the function takes 5.5 seconds to execute (i.e., an order of magnitude longer) :P

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer to omit the functions altogether and re-write the queries so that functions are not used.  Any function that selects data (especially using a "complex join") is a sure way to slow down your query, since the function must be executed once for each row processed (not even necessarily returned) by the main query, maybe 1000s (or 100,000s) of times.

Comment: Indeed... My project is to create an abstraction layer because the queries required are just too complicated for others to use (e.g., in reporting). Functions seemed like the best solution; albeit, in this case, at a performance compromise.

Comment: What about using views to hide the complexity?

Comment: Largely out of consistency, I suppose. I've used functions everywhere -- most of the time, there isn't this kind of problem -- to absolve end users from knowledge of the schema (i.e., required to write joins, even with views to simplify things).

Comment: I see.  Well, SQL isn't really meant for end-users: they prefer something you point and click!